# How can I deploy static assets in vendor directory on Rails / Nginx env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, asset-pipeline

I have built simple Rails application , deployed it on Amazon EC2 instance with capistrano.
It's using some assets installed by bower(I've used bower_components directory) , I've imported it inside vendor/assets directory.
I could import them to application.js and application.css , by adding 'bower_components' directory to Rails asset root directory.

Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "bower_components")

It works well in local environment.
However , I've deployed it on Amazon EC2 , the assets from bower haven't loaded.
I've tracked issue  , and here is my code:

```
@import "Ionicons/css/ionicons.css"
@import "animate.css/animate.css"
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
@import "bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css"
@import "bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css"
@import "bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"
@import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
@import "ionrangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css"
```

This is my application.css.sass.
when working in local env , they(styles in bower_components) could be imported because of bower_components is root directory for asset , too.
When works with nginx on Amazon EC2 instance , Asset root directory is set by nginx config , like below:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

root /home/ubuntu/apps/datraks/current/public;
access_log /home/ubuntu/apps/datraks/current/log/nginx.access.log;
error_log /home/ubuntu/apps/datraks/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    root /home/ubuntu/datraks/current/public;
}
```

nginx only check app's public folder for asset , so the assets in vendor directory could not be imported from application.css.sass

Would you like to help me? Is there any solution to fix this correctly?

Comment: did you try run `rake assets:precompile` after deploy?

Comment: I don't think you understand how this works. The asset compilation takes all the files included by `application.css.sass` and compiles them into one file. `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` is just to tell Rails where to look for file names. Then all the compiled files are put in `public/assets` and that's where Nginx serves them from. If you read capistrano output carefully it's there!

Comment: Mike Szyndel - Thanks for reaching out. Of course I know how asset precompile works. But This is just problem - 
I've imported assets by "@import" , not "require". Do you know how application.css.sass is precompiled in this case? Then the styles are not imported in application.css file directly - remain "@import" itself although application.css is precompiled. I will attach precompiled application.css.scss if you want.

Comment: Oleg Sobchuk - Thanks for your reply. Of course I ran "rake assets:precompile" - It's done as a task of deploy process of capistrano.
Assets are precompiled correctly.